# What does it mean for MySQL to spend a long time "starting" queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

What does it mean if suddenly queries start spending a long time in the `starting` thread state?

This is our RDS Performance Insights dashboard slicing by "waits", showing huge bumps in sessions stuck on "starting":

[image: RDS Performance Insights graph sliced by wait, showing huge bumps in sessions stuck on "waiting", and some bumps on "updating"]

I found info on these in the [General Thread States docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-thread-states.html), but the description of the "starting" thread state is not very helpful:

> The first stage at the beginning of statement execution.

The slicing by query only puzzles me further. `COMMIT` statements seem to correspond to the "starting" waits, but `COMMIT` happens at the end. It'd make me think "locks!", but there are distinct thread states for locks which don't show up here at all.

[image: RDS Performance Insights graph sliced by query, showing the "starting" bumps being attributed to "COMMIT", and the "updating" bumps being attributed to "insert" statements]

## From comments:

Top waits from RDS Performance Insights:

[image: top waits]

Top queries from RDS Performance Insights:

[image: top queries]

Comment: Do you have any queries that touch thousands of rows, such as a big update or delete?

Comment: the interpretation is wrong, when a commt end a lock one of starting prcesses starts

Comment: @RickJames we have a few inserts of < 30 rows, but other than that, I'm not aware

Comment: @nbk do you mean locks will show up long `COMMIT` and as long `starting` times? I do see another metric, `Innodb_row_lock_time`, jumping to 19s during the minute with the slowest commits (it's usually ~64ms), so it would make sense. I'd appreciate (and mark as answered) a more elaborate answer on why it gets tagged as `starting` time and not some of the other lock-related thread states.

Comment: as we don't know what queries you are rinung, it is all speculation, but a bigger update locks and when it is cmmited the next query can run on that lockes table, check the locks

Comment: Can you add your top waits? It is under the database load section.

Comment: @YunusUYANIK just did!